# Setting up network for two places with different static IP addresses by script

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, ip

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 and I'd like to use it at home and at work. At home it could get a DHCP address or a static address 192.168.2.x but at work it must get the static IP address 10.10.34.122.

I know how to assign a static IP address manually by editing `/etc/network/interfaces` but once I do that, I can't reach the device any more if I'm in the other network, so it needs an auto detection.

My idea was to create two files (`/etc/network/home.if` and `/etc/network/work.if`) and copy them as needed. I would start with the 192 address and try to ping my DSL router. If it responds, it should use `home.if`, if not, use `work.if`.

So far I think this script should achieve what I want:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Start with my home setting
cp /etc/network/home.if /etc/network/interfaces
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart

# If I can ping my router, I'm at home
ping=$(ping 192.168.2.1 -c 1)
#echo $ping
if [[ "$ping" =~ "1 received" ]]; then
        echo "home"
        cp /etc/network/home.if /etc/network/interfaces
else
        echo "work"
        cp /etc/network/work.if /etc/network/interfaces
fi

# Apply the detected settings
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Where do I need to put this script that it is executed in the correct place during the startup sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call it from the file /etc/rc.local. You can either add the lines to that file or call the script there. Whatever you choose you have to add it above the line 'exit 0'.

BTW: I suggest you add a wait command after the first network restart because it can take a few seconds for the network to start. If the ping comes to early you can get an incorrect result.

Comment: Yes, I believe it needs some fine-tuning.